# How to align a Linear Layout at the bottom with a "match parent" scroll view on top?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the issue that I want to place an image at the bottom of the screen. How can I achieve the `@+id/bottomImage` to be placed correctly?

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.akrodyn.Innoproject_2021.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pdz" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:text="Search"
            app:backgroundTint="#126FB7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/connect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="Connect"
            app:backgroundTint="#126FB7" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomImage"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"></ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:id="@+id/bottomImage"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/Instructions" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have been playing around but the editor is not showing me the correct setup. It seems that the scrollview is on top of the imageView somehow? If I set the height of the scrollView to some value I get what I want but this of course depends on the phone. I want to make it relative such that it works regardless of the screen size.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct if it helped you, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier if you use a `ConstraintLayout`. So I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.akrodyn.Innoproject_2021.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pdz" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topFrame">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:text="Search"
            android:backgroundTint="#126FB7"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/connect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="Connect"
            android:backgroundTint="#126FB7" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomImage"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomImage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/Instructions" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

On a separate note, I assumed you have a good reason to put a single ImageView in a LinearLayout so I didn't change that. But if you don't, there is no need for that and you can take some of those ImageViews out of the LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 0):

Requirement: The listview has to be aligned above the bottom image and below the linear layout of buttons.

Writing the code in Constraint Layout can definitely make it better. If you want to look into the issues in your code with the Relative Layout as root then this can help.
A few modifications in your code can help us achieve that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.akrodyn.Innoproject_2021.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pdz" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:text="Search"
            app:backgroundTint="#126FB7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/connect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="Connect"
            app:backgroundTint="#126FB7" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomImage"
        android:layout_below="@id/llButtons"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/Instructions" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```